# How to restrict OS X video output to a specific part of the screen

Tags: macos, display

I accidentally bumped my MacBook Pro and now I have several lines on left and bottom sides of the screen.

The effected area is usable but hampers experience. I would like to somehow restrict the output to the working area of the screen.

I remember CRT monitors used to have features to easily, stretch/skew and position output.

How can I do this in OS X 10.10, Yosemite?

Either a built-in feature or a third party application would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called adjusting the overscan; this doesn't technically exist on an LCD screen.

However, I think you can probably manually adjust the usable area of your screen using [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/srx_howtouseit/srx_howtouseit/srx_timings.html).
If you're running El Capitan, you have to do an additional step to enable custom resolutions called [disabling System Integrity Protection (SIP)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html); search their website for a detailed how to.

SwitchResX has a demo version you can test out before buying.

Comment: I had installed its trial version not very long ago. I am not sure if this can help.